# how do i process multiple rows of data from user

Tags: java, database, forms, javabeans

I am using java beans, servlets and jsp (using jstl).
On one of the pages, I have a table with multiple row of data.
for example :

```
 <form action="confirmAndCheckout" method="post">

                    <input type="hidden" name="serviceid" value="4">
                    <input type="hidden" name="eventid" value="0">
                    <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="1">
                    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="10">
                    <input type="hidden" name="datefrom" value="2012-02-07">
                    <input type="hidden" name="dateto" value="2012-05-26">
                    <input type="hidden" name="numdays" value="3">
                    <input type="hidden" name="status" value="pending">
                    <input type="hidden" name="timefrom" value="11:16">
                    <input type="hidden" name="timeto" value="22:07">

                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Proceed to Supplier Confirmation">


<form action="confirmAndCheckout" method="post">

                    <input type="hidden" name="serviceid" value="3">
                    <input type="hidden" name="eventid" value="0">
                    <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="1">
                    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="12">
                    <input type="hidden" name="datefrom" value="2012-02-07">
                    <input type="hidden" name="dateto" value="2012-05-26">
                    <input type="hidden" name="numdays" value="3">
                    <input type="hidden" name="status" value="pending">
                    <input type="hidden" name="timefrom" value="11:16">
                    <input type="hidden" name="timeto" value="22:07">

                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Proceed to Supplier Confirmation">
```

This is on my jsp page. For simplicity I have shown only 2 row of data. For now I have a button in each to make it work, that insert the data row by row.

How can I use only one button to submit all of the rows of data to my servlet which will save the data to the appropriate table?

Comment: You only need one button. Put all these inputs in a single form and assign them unique names (they're duplicates right now).

Comment: @Tom could you please elaborate?